# Jquery UI Touch Punch click event is not working in Android app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have used "Jqueryui-touch-punch" library for dragging and dropping. Dragging, dropping functionality and events is working fine in Chrome browser and on IOS Mobile App.

The problems is that on Android app dragging and dropping is working fine but click events is not working in Android App.

Basically what is happening in the code dragging, dropping and click events on `id="clickinEventFired"` is working fine on chrome browser and ios mobile apps.

But the same code in Android App, Dragging and dropping is working fine but click event is not working.
Always fired drag event when we click on "Drag me around".

Please help me out what mistakes did by me.

code :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    start: startDrag,
    //stop: stopDrag}
  });

  $("#clickinEventFired").click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
  });
});

function startDrag() {
  alert('Dragging event is fired');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p id="clickinEventFired">Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is not what will solve your question, but is there a reason for using jQuery version 1.11 when the current version is 3.4 (6 years of difference) ? I don't know if touchpunch requires a minimun version but in examples it shows the use of version 1.8 of jquery

Comment: Thank you Calvin for the response,
But I have used below libraries also but getting same issues:

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery.ui.menu.min.js" />
            <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js">

Comment: see here: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/215, there is more than one solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think others have given you some good advice already. Touch Punch can help a lot, yet it can also be confusing when events bubble up. In this case, the `tap` event should virtually execute the `click` event. The `tap hold move` should trigger the `drag` event. I would also advise consider making a Handle for your Draggable. This can be very helpful in avoiding  confusing or ambiguous event targets.

Comment: Thank you so much @deblocker for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Mobile devices, you want to be more specific.

Here is an example for a draggable and clickable item.

Desktop Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sd64ux8p/24/

Mobile Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sd64ux8p/24/show/

**HTML**

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-drag-handle">&nbsp;</div>
  <p id="clickinEventFired" class="ui-widget-content">Drag me around</p>
</div>

<div id="log">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#log {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  height: 6em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#log p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ui-widget {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 150px;
}

.ui-drag-handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
}

.ui-widget-content {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function log(str) {
    $("#log").prepend("<p>" + str + "</p>");
  }
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    handle: ".ui-drag-handle",
    start: function() {
      log("Drag Start");
    },
    stop: function() {
      log("Drag Stop");
    }
  });

  $("#clickinEventFired").click(function() {
    log("Handler for .click() called.");
  });
});
```

As we have added a handle, we now create a visual queue where to click to drag. We also separate the event targets so now a "click" cannot be confused for a "drag" event.

Comment: Thank you so much @Twisty for your answer.

Comment: @VikashMishra if it helps you, I hope you will upvote it or mark it as the answer. I would also suggest taking the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour